# Position of title on TIME Series seasonality plots

Tags: python, pandas

df

```
Date        Col1   Col2   Col3
2019-11-1    12     13     14
2019-10-1    2      3      1
2019-03-01   2      1      1 
and so on
```

Code to decompose time series to get seasonality, trends, observed and residual values:

```
 df = df.set_index('Date')
 from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

 for cols in df.columns.values:
    s_dec_multiplicative = seasonal_decompose(df[cols], model = 
    "multiplicative")
    s_dec_multiplicative.plot()
    plt.title(cols)
    plt.show()
```

Now as output I am getting graphs[image]

The problem with these graphs is that I am getting title above Residual graph as shown in pic. I need the title to be above observed graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some fake data, which is hopefully representative. I'm sure (hope) there is a better way to achieve this.

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then form the fake data.

```
# random data
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randint(1, 10, [50, 3])

# dates 
start = pd.datetime(2019, 11, 1)
end = start + pd.DateOffset(days=data.shape[0] - 1)

# dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, 
    index = pd.date_range(start, end), 
    columns = ['col_one', 'col_two', 'col_three']
)
```

Then using the following, you can control which graph has the title. You can access `DecomposeResult` attributes, these are given in `attr` below.

```
attr = ['observed', 'trend', 'seasonal', 'resid']

for col in df:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(attr), 1, sharex=True)
    sd = seasonal_decompose(df[col], model = "multiplicative")

    for idx, a in enumerate(attr):
        s_attr = getattr(sd, a)
        s_attr.plot(ax = ax[idx], title = col if idx == 0 else None)
        ax[idx].set(ylabel= a)
```

[image]

---

### Edit

Added the `ylabels`.

[image]

Comment: Great, no problem

Comment: just one problem, the heading over 4 graphs : observed, residual, trend etc is gone. can that too be available?

Comment: As in can you add ylabels?

Comment: check my graph pic above. on the y axis you have labels observed, residual etc which are missing in your solution pic

Comment: Added this to the code. Although you will have to tweak the positions manually.

Comment: Also unable to get tickers for months like you got here.

Comment: Any idea on how to get gridlines here

Comment: You can add `ax[idx].yaxis.grid(True, which='major')` and `ax[idx].xaxis.grid(True, which='major')` for gridlines. I'm not sure why your x_labels are not showing. For me, they were automatic. Are you dates of type `DatetimeIndex`?